# Remove a blank line when I use writerow with CSV files

Tags: python, csv

I am writing a CSV file, using the next code:

```
import csv

with open("doubt.csv", "w") as outfile:
    csvfile = csv.writer(outfile)
    csvfile.writerow(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']) 
    csvfile.writerow(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
    csvfile.writerow(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
```

The problem is that each time write a row, it puts a "blank line" in the middle of the data:

| -- | -- | -- | -- | -- |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C | D | E |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| A | B | C | D | E |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| A | B | C | D | E |
|  |  |  |  |  |

How can I remove that blank line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add newline='' to avoid extra (empty) lines:

```
import csv

with open("doubt.csv", "w", newline='') as outfile:
    csvfile = csv.writer(outfile)
    csvfile.writerow(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']) 
    csvfile.writerow(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
    csvfile.writerow(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
```